# javascript or jQuery music player

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio-player

I'm in a middle of a project, and the client want a player to play some music.

So, my question is, is there any way with javascript or a jQuery plugin where we have a very small playlist, like 3 or 4 songs or so, and the visitor control the music he/she wants, the volume, etc... Like many flash players we see around the web.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

First result from google :) :)

[jPlayer](http://www.happyworm.com/jquery/jplayer/) is very slick!! see a demo [here](http://www.happyworm.com/jquery/jplayer/latest/demo-02.htm).

---

Some other helpful stuff:

http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/music-player

http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/audio

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with my answer. Was I rude?

Answer (score 3):

I've used [soundmanager2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/) at production and was pleased with.

Answer (score 1):

Dojo has a pluggable abstraction for a [music (and video) player](http://www.dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/av.html).  The main implementation uses Flash.

Answer (score 0):

I have had good results using [JW Player](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-player-now/).  It's pretty easy to get started with too.

Comment: Hey Saul! Thanks for your answer. But this is not what i'm looking for because i want an exclusive music player with a  list of songs and player controls. I've checked the website and i found just a movie player. Thanks anyway ;)

Comment: Tiago, check again. JW Player supports MP3 playback and, in fact, that's all I have ever used it for.  http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/12539/supported-video-and-audio-formats#sound

Answer (score 0):

my plugin Swagg Player will do the trick! http://johnny-ray.com/swaggplayer

demo here http://johnny-ray.com

Answer (score 0):

My online music player jsMusicBox written in just html, js, and php might be perfect for a small setup.
Download from my site here: [jsMusicBox](http://nebraskagamedevelopment.tk/projects/jsMusicBox/)